# how to know when a game is run for the first time

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to play the game storyline and instructions when the game is run for the first time only and bypass them during subsequent runs. How can I set conditions to know when the game is run for the very first time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean first time game play OR first time specific scene execution?

« Here is the way to check if particular class is executed for first time.

```
Static bool isFirstTime = true;

if(isFirstTime)
{
  //do what you need at first time
}
else 
{

}

isFirstTime = false;
```

« If your need is to find first time game launch in device then use Userdefaults to find

```
bool isFirstTime = false;

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Is_FirstTime"])
{
    isFirstTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Is_FirstTime"];
}
else
{
    isFirstTime = true;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:false forKey:@"Is_FirstTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

if(isFirstTime)
{
    //its first time
}
```

Comment: +(void) initialize {}  ?